# why does a border of of 1px width increase a div by 20 pixels?

Tags: html, css

The follwoing html document has two divs, one with a border (`id='with'`) and one without (`id='without`). The div with the border is rendered (at least on firefox and chrome) significantly higher than the one with the border.

I had expected them to vary at most 2 pixels in height, yet, the `alert` tells me that their height is 19 pixels different.

I can't figure out why that is.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Height of divs with/without a border</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>

  <script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function() {

           alert($('#with'   ).height() + ' / ' + 
                 $('#without').height());

    });

  </script>

</head>
<body>

  <div style='width:300px;border:black 1px solid;background-color:yellow' id='with'>
    <h1>With a border</h1>
    bla<br>
    bla<br>
    bla<br>
  </div>

  <div style='width:300px;background-color:green' id='without'>
    <h1>Without a border</h1>
    bla<br>
    bla<br>
    bla<br>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just fiddled this: http://jsfiddle.net/kAZmD/

Comment: I get 74/74 in ie9 and 80/80 in chrome

Comment: @Elliott see my answer below; jsfiddle uses normalise css by default. Disable it and you'll see what the OP means

Comment: Ah! never noticed that checkbox before :) 135/113 now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the `<h1>` element has a top and bottom margin and [these margins are collapsed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/margin_collapsing). There are rules about how the margins are collapsed (i.e. combined). The rule that applies to your example is:

> ## Parent and first/last child
>
> If there is no border, padding, inline content, or clearance to
>   separate the margin-top of a block with the margin-top of its first
>   child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height,
>   min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block
>   with the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse.
>   The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

In your example, the rule can be read as:

- `div#without` does not have a border, its top margin (which is 0) is collapsed with the top margin of `h1` (which is ~20px). *The collapsed margin ends up outside the div*. This means that these 20px do not add to the height of div.
- `div#with` has a border, so the top margin of `h1` (which is ~20px) is rendered *inside* the div, making it 20px taller than expected.

Answer (score 6):

It's because the top margin for the nested `<h1 />` is contained when there is a border. Note @Elliott's fiddle doesn't work because the margins have been removed by jsfiddle's default settings.

EDIT: check this out for more infos http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins